# Pass a variable inside a function Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written this code:

```
var idImg = 'something';
$('#'+idImg).clickToggle(addMarker, destroyMarker);
```

Where clickToggle() is:

```
    $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {

        var funcs = [func1, func2];
        this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
        this.click(function() {
            var data = $(this).data();
            var tc = data.toggleclicked;
            //$.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
            funcs[tc].call(this);
            data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
        });
        return this;
    };
```

And addMarker() is a function which needs to get the variable idImg.

How can I pass the global variable idImg inside the addMarker function?

Thanks

**EDITED**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('img').hover(function() { 
       var idImg = $(this).attr('id');      
       $('#'+idImg).clickToggle(addMarker, destroyMarker);});
  });




 $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {

    var funcs = [func1, func2];
    this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
    this.click(function() {
        var data = $(this).data();
        var tc = data.toggleclicked;
        $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
        data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
    });
    return this;
 };

var addMarker = function(){ alert(idImg)}  <-- I WANT THIS

 var destroyMarker = function(){
        DO SOMETHING ELSE
 };
```

Comment: If you're consistently using it as an ID, you can use `this.id` to retrieve it inside whatever function you're running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function

```
$('#'+idImg).clickToggle(function(){
    addMarker(idImg)
}, destroyMarker);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y0hqse5g/2/)

But in this case since that is the id of the button, `this` inside `addMarker` refers to the button so you could also use `this.id` to refer to `something`.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y0hqse5g/1/)

Comment: Actually the button is the image. This is what I toggle.

Comment: Hmm. I try both but doesnt seem to work. In the first case I added the anonymous function and the idImg as input in the addMarker() but didnt work.

Comment: @dkar can you recreate your problem in the attached fiddle

Comment: @dkar `function(idImg){ alert(idImg)}`